# legend to line types using scale_linetype_manual in ggplot not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a 3 lines, one is dashed and others are solid. I have to add legend for dashed and solid lines. But the legend is not shown in the plot.

```
plot <- data_this_shop %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y= price)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=mean(price)), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(data = data_other_shops, aes(x=id, y=lower_95), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(data = data_other_shops, aes(x=id, y=upper_95), linetype = "solid") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "solid"),
                        labels = c( "Mean price", "95% CI"))
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try moving `linetype` to *inside* the `aes()` function. For example, `geom_line(aes(y = mean(price), linetype = "Mean price"))`.

Comment: As @teunbrand indicates: There is a rule of thumb to memorize: "What is inside `aes()` will get a legend. See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72163827/how-can-i-show-legend-of-multiple-layers-geom-point-and-geom-bar>

Comment: @teunbrand It worked. If you add it as answer, I will accept it. Thanks :)